# Eclipse LTK refactoring - Resources path not being updated when project is renamed

Tags: overriding, eclipse-rcp, rename, automated-refactoring

I am writing custom refactoring for renaming project/folder/file in Eclipse RCP application. I have extended the [Refactoring](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fltk%2Fcore%2Frefactoring%2Fpackage-summary.html) class and wrote my own ResourceChange class where I am updating the project resources by calling [IProject.move()](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fresources%2FIProject.html) method.

The rename is working fine but path of the resources under the project are not updated.

Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks.

Update:

Refactoring class Code:

```
@Override
public Change createChange(IProgressMonitor pm) {
    pm.beginTask("Renaming", 1);
    CompositeChange change = new CompositeChange("Renaming");
    if(resource instanceof IProject) {
    return new CustomResourceChange((IProject)resource, resourceName);
    }

    pm.done();
    return change;
}
```

CustomResourceChange class code:

```
protected IPath createNewPath() {
    return modifiedResourcePath.removeLastSegments(1).append(resourceNewName);
}

@Override
public Change perform(IProgressMonitor pm) throws CoreException {
    try {
        pm.beginTask("Renaming Project", 1);
        Change change = new CustomResourceChange(modifiedResource, createNewPath(), resourceOldName, resourceNewName);
        IProject project = (IProject)ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().findMember(modifiedResourcePath);
        if (project != null) {
            IProjectDescription description = project.getDescription();
            description.setName(resourceNewName);
            project.move(description, IResource.FORCE, new SubProgressMonitor(pm, 1));
        }
        return change;
    } finally {
        pm.done();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show us your code. You might also want to look at the existing `MoveResourceChange` class.

Comment: Hi @greg-449 , I have added the code.

Comment: You might want to look at the source of `org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.refactoring.RenamePluginProcessor` to see how it handles renaming a project.

Comment: I am referring the RenamePluginProcessor code but path of the file (present in project) is not being update if the file is opened in editor

Comment: It is up to the editor to listen for resource changes and react. Some editors do listen, others don't.

Comment: Okay.  I thought when we update project it directly updates the editor. Also on project architecture side, Is it a good practice to extend the Refactoring class? or Should I add an RenameParticipant extension?